# MobileFirst 7.1 Server Configuration Tool - Admin Console deployment failed with JVM error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am trying to deploy the MobileFirst Admin Operational console using Server Configuration Tool. Started the configuration tool as root user. Create a configuration and saved the xml. Pressed the "Deploy" button. Its failed with JVM terminated Exit code -1 error.

- MobileFirst Server Version 7.1.0.0-MFPF-Server-IF201510051721
- WebSphere 8.5.5.7
- Installation Manager JRE:jre_7.0.7001.20140909_1712

After this error, I am able to see the Admin console application and admin services application in WebSphere. But in Configuration Tool not able to create / add runtime under this configuration. It says no configuration found.

[image: JVM Error]

Comment: The exit code in the screenshot is 1, not -1.

Comment: Does the file `$HOME/.IBM/MobileFirst Platform Server/configuration-tool-workspace/.metadata/.log` contain any error messages or stack traces?

Comment: In case this is due to the JRE you use, can you try with the JRE that comes with install Manager ? If you open <MFPInstallDir>/shortcuts/consfiguration-tool.sh, it starts with a definition of the value im_java_home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After this error, I am able to see the Admin console application and admin services application in WebSphere. But in Configuration Tool not able to create / add runtime under this configuration. It says no configuration found.

This is not a solution to the JVM crash you experiment, but a workaround to enable to be able to add the runtime (I understand from the above description that the crash happens after the Server Configuration Tool saved the configuration and deployed it).

Go to (homeDir)/.mobilefirst_platform_server/server-configuration-tool. You should find a directory named after your configuration. In that directory, you should find a file named (ConfigName).xml. Copy this file as (ConfigName).lastdeployed (ie same name as the xml file but change the suffix). The Server Configuration Tool would have created this file after deployment completion (and uses it for later operations such as uninstall) and it uses it as an indicator that the configuration is deployed.